# Ember js pre 4 - router not resolving id on link click

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of accounts and then i have a view link to view an account in detail and this is the account route. When i click the view link the (guid) doesnt update when going through the router, it only updates in the URL but it doesnt seem to be carrying through to the code.

When i do a browser refresh then the (guid) gets carried through to the router... Its not resolving for some reason.

Im not using ember-data but will use it in the future.

Here is my "Accounts" template code with the "View" link:

```
{{#each accountdata in controller}}
<tr>
<td>{{accountdata.accountnumber}}</td>
<td>{{accountdata.accountname}}</td>
<td>{{accountdata.accounttypestatus}}</td>
<td>{{accountdata.accountuser}}</td>
<td>{{#linkTo account accountdata}}View{{/linkTo}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

accountdata is the context with the "accountguid" which is my id.

Here is my router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("accounts", { path: '/accounts' });
    this.resource("account",  { path: "/accounts/:accountguid" });
});

App.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('searchfilter','ALL');
        controller.search();
    }
});

App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {        
        controller.show(controller);
    },
    model: function(params) {
        this.controllerFor('account').set('accountguid',params.accountguid);        
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return {accountguid: Em.get(model, 'accountguid')}
    }
});
```

My controller.show is where i send the context to call a script to display the account details.

So i just need view to carry through the correct accountguid each time which it isnt and then to call the show(context) method.

Thanks

This is my old router code which worked 100%. When i clicked a link it resolved the :accountguid and when i did a browser refresh it did the same thing. i had no problems, everything just worked.

```
//         //Accounts
//         accounts: Ember.Route.extend({
//             route: '/accounts',
//             index: Ember.Route.extend({
//                 route: '/',
//                 connectOutlets: function (router) {
//                     router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('accounts');
//                     router.get('accountsController').set('searchfilter','ALL');
//                     router.get('accountsController').search();
//                 }
//             }),
//             view: Ember.Route.extend({
//                 route: '/:accountguid',

//                 connectOutlets: function (router, account) {
//                     router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('account', account);
//                     router.get('accountController').show(account);                    

//                     //router.get('accountController').connectOutlet('eventloghistory','eventloghistory');                    
//                 }
//             })
//         }),
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem with the following code. I am now able to refresh the browser and i am able to click the link and it will carry through the current :accountguid in use to the show() method.

```
App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return {accountguid: params.accountguid};
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {        
        controller.show(model);
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return {accountguid: Em.get(model, 'accountguid')}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your router map to the following and it should work

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("accounts", function(){
    this.resource('account',{path:':account_id'});
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I dont understand why it would be :account_id when my context has :accountguid... When i click the view link using your code i get /trunk/web/#/accounts/undefined now. Im lost.

Comment: That's convention, then your account route handler will automatically resolve /#/accounts/1. Well that's if you want to benefit from free wiring :).

Answer (score 0):

Please, show us the code behind your AccountsController and AccountController. It would be most useful if you provide a jsfiddle with the whole construction.

In general, you may be unaware of the new flow of things. Here is what happens in the two scenarios:
1. You navigate to the AccountRoute by setting the URL (/account/5 for example).
1.1. the 'model' hook of the AccountRoute is called

```
model: function(params) {
    return your model here...
}
```

with params = { accountguid: 5 }. Because you are not using ember-data, you should implement this hook and initialise and return the model there.
1.2. the setupController hook is called with the AccountController and the model returned by the model hook. Without the code behind

```
controller.show(controller);
```

It is not quite clear what its purpose is, but you should probably do something like

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  controller.set('content', model);
  controller.show(model);
}
```

As you can see, by not implementing the model hook, you URL stays correct, but the route does not know how to build the needed model resource.

2. You transition to the route via a linkTo call

   {{#linkTo account accountdata}}View{{/linkTo}}

Here, linkTo expects accountdata to be the full account model for the route. Meaning it may not carry only partial data like id for example (read this for clearance: [In latest Ember, how do you link to a route with just the id/name of a model, rather than providing all of its attributes in the linking page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367517/in-latest-ember-how-do-you-link-to-a-route-with-just-the-id-name-of-a-model-ra)). 
2.1. The model hook of the AccountRoute is **NOT** called. The AccountRoute model property is set to the object that is passed to linkTo instead (in our case 'accountdata').
2.2. setupController is called with AccountController and the accountdata object.
If you accountdata object is not complete, it would be wise to create a complete instance here and set it to the controller.

As you can imagine, if you accountdata is like { id: 5, accountname: "John", accounttypestatus: "A", ...}, then after a click on linkTo, the URL will update correctly to /account/5, but the account template will receive accountdata, rather than an actual account.

P.P. If none of the above is any help, this might be your issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1709